# Total number of words with exactly one character larger than preceding character

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have to count the total number of words which satisfies the following property-

1. Has a length $n$ (where $1\le n\le26$)
2. Contains only unique lowercase characters
3. Exactly one character is lexicographicaly greater than the preceding character.

Example, for $n=2$, the number of such words is $325 [ab,ac,ad,\dots,bc,bd,be,\dots,yz]$

I have got the formula total words $=\ _{26}C_{n}\cdot(2^n-(n+1))$  by some observation but can't justify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first select the letters. Then we divide them into two. Then we arrange each group in descending alphabetical order. Then we concatenate these two sequence.

Number of ways to choose $n$ letters: $\binom{26}{n}$

Number of ways to divide $n$ letters into two: $2^{n}-2$. However, if the first group contains the $i$ highest letters, $i=1,...,n-1$, then our steps will result in fully descending sequence of letters. Thus we substract $n-1$ to obtain $2^{n}-(n+1)$.

$\binom{26}{n}\times\left(2^{n}-(n+1)\right)$